# Cannot email via gmail

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Unable to send mail via gmail in Symfony 2.8.3 in prod on freebsd host while it works on Windows 10 with same source code in both prod & dev. [Also unable to get a log of mailing on host, which might help resolve this.]

Update: Mail can be sent using PHP's `mail()` function. Using Swiftmailer to send mail from a controller does not work. Changed parameters to use `mailer_transport: smtp mailer_host: localhost` does not enable Swiftmailer to send from a controller.

parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: {valid address}
mailer_password: (valid password}
```

config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
```

config_prod.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        mail:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      buffered
        buffered:
            type:    buffer
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: "%mailer_user%"
            to_email:   "%mailer_user%"
            subject:    Error report!
            level:      debug
```

Comment: Why did this get a close vote? The app is using Monolog to (try to) send error alerts.  Should I just abandon Monolog and write my own exception handler to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any other solution or finding a way to log Swiftmailer behavior I added a custom exception listener to send mail locally.